# Higher Discrete logarithms over finite fields

Tags: finite-fields, polylogarithms

The polylogarithm function is defined by $$Li_s(z)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{z^k}{k^s}.$$ At $s=1$, we have the natural logarithm function. We have the inverse of natural logarithm function as the exponential function.

Over finite fields, the inverse of an exponential function is taken as discrete logarithm (given $a,g$ as elements of a cyclic group generated by $g$, the element $x$ in $g^x=a$ is the discrete logarithm of $a$).

Is it sensible to ask for definitions of the analogs of higher logarithms for $s>1$ over finite fields?

Comment: How do you compute it for s > 1?

Comment: I do not know. I am just asking if there are analogs for $s>1$.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you will find something of interest in Amnon Besser's paper, [Finite and p-adic polylogarithms.](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0006051)

The abstract says,

The finite $n$-th polylogarithm $li_n(z)$ in $Z/p[z]$ is defined as the sum on $k$ from $1$ to $p-1$ of $z^k/k^n$. We state and prove the following theorem. Let $Li_k:C_p \to C_p$ be the $p$-adic polylogarithms defined by Coleman. Then a certain linear combination $F_n$ of products of polylogarithms and logarithms, with coefficients which are independent of $p$, has the property that $p^{1-n} DF_n(z^p)$ reduces modulo $p>n+1$ to $li_{n-1}(z)$ where $D$ is the Cathelineau operator $z(1-z) d/dz$. A slightly modified version of this theorem was conjectured by Kontsevich. This theorem is used by Elbaz-Vincent and Gangl to deduce functional equations of finite polylogarithms from those of complex polylogarithms.